# Maven is behaving differently on diffrent system with same pom configuration

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am working on project with my friends in which there are lot of dependencies which are required by lot of modules.

```
Scenario is like this :-
```

i am using datastax drivers for apache_cassandra and  spark_cassandra_connector which requires different versions of io.netty modules.

spark_cassandra_connector requires cassandra-driver-core which i am already using in my project.

First problem arrived on my friend's laptop which was some netty-epoll error that it didn't find some method although mine was working fine without any error.(same pom.xml)

After working on error we found out there were different versions of io.netty which was used by project dependencies which may be causing the error.

so we used global version of io.netty modules that is :-

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
                <version>${netty.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
                <version>${netty.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That Problem was fixed .

Now same method not found error is happening in my friends laptop with cassandra-driver-core . so we decided to use cassandra drivers globally 
that is :-

```
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

which is not working.

i have tried excluding cassandra-driver-core from spark connectors

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

which also didn't work and this problem is happening on friends system not mine.

is there any thing i need to know about maven or does any body knows why it is happening version i am using has that method.

why other system is not picking up that version or overriding other version which is used by spark module.

i have checked dependency tree on both systems in verbose which shows the same output (in case maven is picking up another version on other system but which is not case also)

i have tried cleaning the .m2 folder on other system which also didn't work.

what can be the solution ??

Comment: Are you using the same version of Maven, all plugins in your build are identical...using the same JDK version? Furthermore have you checked via `mvn dependency:tree` and compared the results?

Comment: Try comparing effective pom on both nodes `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: One of you may have a polluted local repository.  Try removing `.m2/repository` in both your home directories and rebuild (will probably download half the world).

Comment: A "poluted" local cache should never cause issues otherwise the project is wrongly behaving...

Comment: yes the version is same in both systems